# node:events:491 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event npm enoent. Why are these error messages coming?

Tags: node-modules, child-process, npm-scripts

I am trying to run my node.js project in my windows laptop. however it worked in mac PC, but it is showing same error :
PS C:\Program Files\linkedin-bayone-main> node index.js
Server listening on port 3000
MN1 : lnurl :: https://www.linkedin.com/in/ambarjain/
node:events:491
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: spawn npm ENOENT
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn npm',
path: 'npm',
spawnargs: [ 'run', 'test:linkedin' ]
}

I tried using cache clearing and installing-uninstalling node, npm and vs code. However it is not helping in anyway.